# Getting OpenLDAP integration issue with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, openldap

I'm planning the structure of OpenLDAP server to integrate it with multiple applications(lets say 10 applications). In this I have 8 internal applications (Web and Mobile Applications) and 2 others say external services like Wordpress.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd4xU.png)

In OpenLDAP, I have created 3 groups(cn=users, cn=roles, cn=applications). Here I have used organizationalRole to create roles, and groupOfUniqueNames to create applications. In Wordpress there are 5 different roles (administrator, subscriber, contributor,editor,author) and need to give LDAP User Mapping Configurations in WordPres. There I am getting issues i.e., user is not present in that path. I have tried search base as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com and search filter as (&(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=?))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzKOJ.png)

How to configure search base and search filter to authenticate user in WordPress?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did that image come from? Is that a plugin? You should name the software you are using.

Comment: I have used ldap-login-for-intranet-sites plugin for WordPress. In LDAP, we need to include LDAP roles(admin, developer etc.,) as well as Wordpress roles (administrator, subsciber, editor etc.,)to give access/authenticate users . So internal applications will use LDAP roles. And for WordPress, we will use roles which are defined in plugin. So the solution would fit for my internal applications and WordPress also.

If there are any changes regarding user structure that I may need to implement in LDAP, please suggest me.